# Don't wait for response and print the result immediately

Tags: php

I have a function sendSMSMessage() and it runs after printing some results:

```
<?php
...
print $x;
sendSMSMessage(params);
...
?>
```

This process of this function might take too long time of running and the app has to wait a long time before getting a response so i would like to print the results regardless of whether the `sendSMSMessage` has done...

Comment: ob_flush before the function is called, if the content is printed already

Comment: PHP does not support real Threading. You might use PHP Gearman for threading